# Select everything to the right of a specific character

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

Given this data:

```
Home: (708) 296-2112
```

I want everything to the right of the `:` character.

This is what I have so far, but I'm getting no results:

```
right(phone1, locate(':', phone1 + ':')-1) phone
```

If I use `left` instead of `right`, I get just "HOME" - just for testing purposes. I know I'm close, but I'm missing something.

Comment: How about `substring(phone1, locate(':', phone1) + 1, length(phone1))`

Comment: Will it perhaps be `Work:`, `Mobile:` rows as well?

Comment: @jarlh The answer is yes, see one of the (now) deleted answers.

Comment: You should add some more sample data, with different number types, and also the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING` (might be `SUBSTR` dependent on your version) instead:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(phone1, LOCATE(':', phone1) + 1, LENGTH(phone1))
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: i dont think stubstring or substr works with advantage. or at least ive never got it working

Comment: sorry i was doing something wrong, thanks that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without hard-coding in `Home:`, so you can also use `Office:` or `Mobile:` or `Fax:`, or any other word followed by a colon.

This uses ADS's scripting ability to use a variable and the built-in `System.iota` single row table (similar to Oracle's `dual`). You can just use the last line, replacing `test` with the name of your column and `system.iota` with the name of your table.

```
declare test string;
set test = 'Home: (708) 296-2112';
select substring(test, position(':' in test) + 1, length(test)) from system.iota;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RIGHT function as follows:

```
RIGHT(phone1, LEN(phone1)-CHARINDEX(':', phone1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, but your algebra is off.  You want to take the full length of the string offset by the position of the colon, minus one:

```
right(phone1, length(phone1) - locate(':', phone1) - 1)
```

Comment: I ran through the logic in my answer several times, and it checked out each time.  I don't know what to suggest to you `\:-|`